# Can you speed up Xcode's ‘folding’ animations in the code editor?

Tags: xcode, refactoring, xcode9

The title really says the entire question. I’m trying to find a way to speed up the “folding” animations when doing rename-refactoring.

While I don’t mind the animations themselves per se, I do tend to get frustrated that they take as long as they do, especially when doing multiple renames.

So... does anyone know of a preference or setting that would allow me to tweak/disable this feature?

Comment: Try AppCode instead. I'm quite serious, not trolling.

Comment: I keep playing around with the demos, but never seriously.  Mostly just to see what it looks like. However, you're not the first to say that at all. Perhaps I should take a deeper look.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

hey you can use this command in terminal and restart Xcode.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode CodeFoldingAnimationSpeed -float 0.25
```

Comment: Bingo!  Except... it looks like this is the number of seconds.  You should change it to -float and 0.25 which is nice and fast, but you can still see it folding.

Comment: defaults write http://com.apple.dt.Xcode CodeFoldingAnimationSpeed -int 0 make it zero u will  not seeing any animation.

Comment: Yes, but again, the value is a float, not an int.  Granted, for the value '0' (zero) it doesn't make any difference, but for people coming here for information, they need to know it's a float.  You should consider updating your answer to reflect that. (That and using 20 is reeeaaallllyyyyy looooonnnngggggg!)  :)

Answer (score 5):

System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Reduce motion

Comment: This worked, but I didn't really want to disable everything system-wide, just in Xcode. That said, maybe there's a happy medium: Is there a master duration for system animations?